# Comparing two dataframes on given columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have two dataframes DF1 and DF2 with different column sets

```
------------------------------------------------
DF1                                                 
col1 col2 col3  col4 col5   col6    col7 
---------------------------------------------           
Asr  Suh  dervi xyz  yes    NY      2022-04-11      
Bas  nav  dervi xyz  yes    CA      2022-04-11      
Naz  adn  otc   xyz   no    NJ      2022-05-01    

---------------------------------------------------

DF2
col1 col2 col3 col4 
------------------------------------------------------
Asr  Suh  dervi xyz  
Bas  nav  dervi xyz  
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to compare these two dataframes based on col2 and Col3 and filter out non matching rows from DF1.

So compare operation should give below row in dataset

```
df3
Naz  adn  otc  xyz   no NJ  2022-05-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no left anti join in pandas, use outer join with indicator=True first.

```
cols = ['col2', 'col3']
# add _merge columns via outer join
_df = df1[cols].merge(df2[cols], how='outer', indicator=True)
_df
col2    col3    _merge
Suh     dervi   both
nav     dervi   both
adn     otc     left_only

# extract left_only, and drop _merge column
_df = _df[_df._merge=='left_only'].drop('_merge', axis=1)
_df
col2    col3
adn     otc

# inner join df1 and _df
df3 = df1.merge(_df, on=cols)
df3

col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7
Naz     adn     otc     xyz     no      NJ      2022-05-01
```

Comment: Thanks for your response .. it somehow dint gave me differences on left side. What is _merge here ?

Comment: _merge is the indicator column added by the outer join, see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html, So we use the outer join to extract left_only part into an auxiliary data frame _df, and inner join df1 with _df

Comment: I added some more detail above ... the code works in pandas 1.3.5, python 3.7

Comment: I am somehow getting error "Can only compare identically -labelled series objects" in this. I tried to reset the index and also use equals but dint helped. I am using 1.3.4 pandas and python 3.7

Comment: Well by sorting index it worked for me thanks much !!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pyspark's `left anti` join to get your desired result. When you join two DataFrame using Left Anti Join (leftanti), it returns only columns from the left DataFrame for non-matched records.

Preparing the dataframes,

```
data_1 = [('Asr',  'Suh', 'dervi', 'xyz', 'yes', 'NY', '2022-04-11'),
('Bas','nav','dervi','xyz', 'yes', 'CA', '2022-04-11'),
('Naz','adn','otc','xyz', 'no', 'NJ', '2022-05-01')]

col_1 = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7']

df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data_1, schema = col_1)

df_1.show()
```

```
+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----------+
|col1|col2| col3|col4|col5|col6|      col7|
+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----------+
| Asr| Suh|dervi| xyz| yes|  NY|2022-04-11|
| Bas| nav|dervi| xyz| yes|  CA|2022-04-11|
| Naz| adn|  otc| xyz|  no|  NJ|2022-05-01|
+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----------+
```

```
data_2 = [('Asr',  'Suh', 'dervi', 'xyz'),
('Bas','nav','dervi','xyz')]

col_2 = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

df_2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data_2, schema = col_2)

df_2.show()
```

```
+----+----+-----+----+
|col1|col2| col3|col4|
+----+----+-----+----+
| Asr| Suh|dervi| xyz|
| Bas| nav|dervi| xyz|
+----+----+-----+----+
```

So, in your case, you could try something like this,

```
df_1.join(df_2, (df_1.col2 == df_2.col2) & (df_1.col3 == df_2.col3), "leftanti").show(truncate=False)
```

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7      |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
|Naz |adn |otc |xyz |no  |NJ  |2022-05-01|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
```

or

```
df_1.join(df_2, ['col2', 'col3'], "leftanti").select(df_1.columns).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7      |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
|Naz |adn |otc |xyz |no  |NJ  |2022-05-01|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
```

Both of them are the same just different syntax, use which ever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar I am somehow getting error "Can only compare identically -labelled series  objects" in this. I tried to reset the index and also use equals but dint helped. I am using 1.3.4 pandas and python 3.7